# I get an error when i make post request on Twilio sending sms api in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I am learning Twilio Sending SMS tool. I created a trial account and have a verified phone number too.

I made post request to send sms through my aspx page but I got an authentication error.

Here is the code. Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
string url ="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+accontSid+ ":" + authenticationToken +"/SMS/Messages.json";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
var authInfo = accSid + ":" + authToken;
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
request.Method = "POST";
var postData = "{\"To\":" +"\"" + ToNumber + "\"" + ", \"From\":" + "\"" + FromNumber + "\"" + ", \"Body\":" + "\"" + Body + "\"}";

var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
//request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream writer = null;
writer = request.GetRequestStream();
writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
writer.Close();

request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic"+authInfo;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
{"code": 20003, "detail": "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.", "message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003", "status": 401}
```

What changes I should make?

**Edit Change**

```
 try
 {
            string url ="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+accountSid+"/SMS/Messages.json";

            string FromNumber = "+12012317746";
            string ToNumber = "+91xxxxxxxxxx";
            string Body = "Hello This is my test account.";


            TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(accSid, authToken);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            var authInfo = accSid + ":" + authToken;
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
            request.Method = "POST";
            var postData = "{\"To\":" +"\"" + ToNumber + "\"" + ", \"From\":" + "\"" + FromNumber + "\"" + ", \"Body\":" + "\"" + Body + "\"}";

            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            Stream writer = null;
            writer = request.GetRequestStream();
            writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            writer.Close();
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic "+authInfo;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            client.SendMessage("+12012317746 ", txtToNo.Text, txtMsg.Text);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). You don't use the token in the request URI.

Comment: @CodeCaster No need to be like that. Jui is just learning.

Comment: @philnash how can one learn if one doesn't read? I also don't find my previous comment particularly offensive, hostile or otherwise "like that".

Comment: It wasn't particularly friendly. I'd expect StackOverflow to be a bit more welcoming to new developers.

Comment: @philnash I don't see why, or how I would have phrased that comment differently. Should I have started with _"How nice that you decided to pick up programming, and welcome to the site!"_ or something?

Comment: I think your actual answer below was much nicer, thanks for following up :)

Comment: @phil back when I posted the comment, I didn't have time to write a full-blown answer. I also just now discovered that you're from Twilio, so I can understand you want to interact somewhat more friendly with your userbase than a random passer-by. Also, don't confuse terseness with unfriendliness. :)

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is a couple of issues here. As CodeCaster pointed out, you do not need the Auth Token as part of the URL, just the Account SID.

Your Authorization header looks as though it is set up incorrectly, you don't have a space between "Basic" and the `authInfo`.

You have also set up the request type as "application/json". [Twilio expects your POST request to have form encoded data as the body and the content type `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/request#post).

Twilio actually supply a [C# helper library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) that you can use to make sending messages in Asp.net easier. You don't need to worry about the basic setup of the HTTP request and can just get on with building your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with this code. The error itself is already pretty clear; this request provides a response which you should read:

```
detail: Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.
message: Authentication Error - No credentials provided
more_info: https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003
```

Read the errors, visit the mentioned "more info" page and [read the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). The problems with your code:

1. You only have to provide the Account ID in the request URI, so lose the `+ ":" + authenticationToken`.
2. You're not properly writing the basic authentication header. You're missing a space between "Basic" and the base64-encoded credentials.
3. Borrowed from the just-posted other answer: the content-type of the request also is incorrect.
4. As explained in the "more info" and documentation links above, use a client library. You don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Especially if you look at the last point, all of this code could be replaced with the following:

```
string AccountSid = "AC5ef872f6da5a21de157d80997a64bd33"; 
string AuthToken = "[AuthToken]"; 
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken); 

var message = twilio.SendMessage(
    "+14158141829", "+16518675309", 
    "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!", ...);
```

Comment: I am doing like that @CodeCaster but i want to do it with post request only.